# Tooltipster html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltipster

I don't know for what reason but in tooltipster html content won't display. I encoded the html, added the option in the script but still a string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/css/tooltipster.css">
<span title="&amp;lt;img src=&amp;quot;my-image.png&amp;quot; /&amp;gt; &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt; This text is in bold case !&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;" class="tooltip">Why is this not working</span>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/s38oja1q/1/

Comment: But I need it in html title not in JS. Because I need to generate it in a title.

Comment: here's the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/s38oja1q/2/ in html title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your title attribute has a bunch of instances of `&amp;` where it should just be `&`.

For example, you have:

```
&amp;lt;img src=&amp;quot;my-image.png&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;
```

When it should be:

```
&lt;img src=&quot;my-image.png&quot; /&gt;
```

I'm not sure how you generated your title attribute, it looks like you may have escaped the string twice.

---

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/css/tooltipster.css">
<span class="tooltip" title="&lt;img src=&quot;my-image.png&quot; /&gt; &lt;strong&gt; This text is in bold case !&lt;/strong&gt;">This is working</span>
```